# Trouble creating my own web app similar to diablo 3 journey tracker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to make my own tracker for another game for local use (not planning to put it up on the web) and I've been having trouble making the cells of the table respond when I click on them so that they get marked with a tick just like the table in https://d3resource.com/journey/index.php.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#td-sj1a").click(function() {
      $("#td-sj1a").addClass("done");
    });
  });
</script>

<table class="Layout">

  <tr class="sjtable">
    <th id="th-1" class="sjtable"></th>
    <th id="th-2" class="sjtable"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <td id="td-sj1a" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    <td id="td-sj2a" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <td id="td-sj1b" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    <td id="td-sj2b" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <td id="td-sj1c" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    <td id="td-sj2c" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <td id="td-sj1d" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    <td id="td-sj2d" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <td id="td-sj1e" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    <td id="td-sj2e" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <td id="td-sj1f" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    <td id="td-sj2f" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

After a few days I have managed to make it work in the most messy way possible and it is not efficient as it won't work on the following pages of the site I'm making. This is the script I am using for it but I have to specify every ID separately, which also means I have to write this several times for each ID.

I want to write a function which will retrive the IDs of all the cells I have in the table. The format of the IDs are as followed: td-sj1a, td-sj1b, td-sj2a, td-sj2b, and it goes up until I have about 10-15 different IDs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of referencing your table cells by ID, try using the class name (in your case, *sjitem*) instead.

In the click handler function, you can reference the element that was clicked using *$(this)*.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.sjitem').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("done");
  });
});
```

```css
.sjitem {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: silver;
}
.done {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <th id="th-1" class="sjtable"></th>
    <th id="th-2" class="sjtable"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <td id="td-sj1a" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    <td id="td-sj2a" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <td id="td-sj1b" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    <td id="td-sj2b" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <td id="td-sj1c" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    <td id="td-sj2c" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <td id="td-sj1d" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    <td id="td-sj2d" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <td id="td-sj1e" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    <td id="td-sj2e" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sjtable">
    <td id="td-sj1f" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
    <td id="td-sj2f" class="sjtable sjitem"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```